# How are tables aligned to top in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with 7 tables. At runtime, their placement is justified but I want them to align to top. How can I do it?

I have this:

[image]

but I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for this type of alignment, you would create rectangles, then place the control (such as a table/matrix, textbox etc) within the rectangles.

Then on the **Report** properties, you need to set the `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` to `True`

You can also set `CanGrow` = `False` on some objects, but do this last and only if required.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I solved it with rectangles. A cordial greeting from Argentina.